# Eclipse wont read my device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, device, samsung-mobile

I was using my phone earlier today for testing apps. I plugged it in later today to test another and eclipse wouldn't recognize it. I looked everywhere. I'm not sure why it wont work. Im using a Samsung Galaxy S3 device. All of the drives properly installed and updated. And debuggin is on.

Comment: Windows or Linux? Is USB debugging on?

Comment: Have tried this:  'Deployment target selection mode' to manual (Debug configurations -> target tab)

Comment: @Floradu88 "Samsung Galaxy" is *not code*. Please stop making edits like this.

Comment: @AndrewBarber yeah, but it should be highlighted

Comment: @Floradu88 No, it should not. Even if it should be, you should do it with *italics*, not highlighting as code. But some of your edits you are 'highlighting' so much that the post becomes unreadable. Please stop editing in highlights. they are not helpful.

Comment: I won't edit any of them, they are all yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only used my phone to test for one day. And all day i had my phone connected cause i was teathering. I turned my teather back on and viola, problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem with eclipse, devices get detected by adb(Android Debug Bridge that comes with the SDK) and the underlying driver(Install Samsung Kies to get the correct driver for S3), Ensure you have the correct drivers installed. Then it will detect successfully. Ensure USB debugging connected in Settings -> Developer Options

Answer (score 0):

Install google usb driver throu android sdk manager